Add and delete items in drag and drop list
I have to rework a program (javascript & html). So I thought of using Tauri and Sevlte to give it a stand-alone version in a newer look. Taking the first steps is never easy, especially if you are more of a C programmer than C++ or anything else :-(
Here is my problem:
I create a drag&drop zone with draggable elements:
using 'svelte-dnd-action'.
in my main file "+page.svelte" I create an array holding the entries:
import SortableList from ./SortableList.svelte
 
let sensors = [ 
    {id: 0, title: 'USB1'},
    {id: 1, title: 'USB2'},
    {id: 2, title: 'USB3'},
    {id: 3, title: 'File: abc.txt'},
    {id: 4, title: 'File: 123.txt'},        
];

then I call
<SortableList list = {sensors}/>
Inside "SortableList.svelte" I loop over all list elements and call "ListElement.svelte" to display the element. (I know, I could do this directly here...)
<section use:dndzone={{items: list, dropFromOthersDisabled}}
    on:consider={handleSort}
    on:finalize={handleSort}>    
    {#each list as item (item.id) }
        <div animate:flip={{ duration: flipDurationMs }}>
        <ListElement count = {item.id} id = {item.title}/>
    </div>
    {/each}
</section>

"ListElement.svelte" then creates the list-item to be displayed:
<div class="ListElement">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <h1 class ={id}>{id}</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <div >
            <p class ="{id}, IDtag" style="margin: 0px">{@html ListBoxString}:{count}</p>
        </div>
        <div >
            <button class={id} on:click={ListBoxClick}>{id}: Clicked {count} {count === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

All of this works fine...... until I start working with the list. I have a button on that adds a new element to the array "sensors" This I have in "+page.svelte":
function buttonClick(){
    let i=sensors.length;
        sensors = [...sensors,{id:i, title:'great'}];
}

It works :-), but if I manually sorted the list by drag&drop, adding an element restores the original order! :-(
I would also like to add a "delete" button to each list element. But my guess: this would end in a similar problem. Having browsed for this "resorting issue" for hours I decided to ask the community.
What I tried:

renumbering the id values in "SortableList.svelte" I use the function "on:finalize..."... ugly animation, adding another element resorts the list.
using "on:drop" I get an  "A11y: <section> with drop handler must have an ARIA role" error.

Well, I am sure there is a simple and elegant way to cover this problem.
Many thanks to all reading my question and maybe answering it.

You are just missing a binding, the changes from within SortableList (the reordering) is not propagating back out.
<SortableList bind:list={sensors} />

REPL
(If ListElement changes properties, you may need additional bindings threre. You probably should not be changing the id if that is used for identification.)

Side note: If SortableList is supposed to be generic, it should be using a slot:
<section use:dndzone={{ items: list, dropFromOthersDisabled }}
    on:consider={handleSort}
    on:finalize={handleSort}>    
    {#each list as item (item.id)}
        <div animate:flip={{ duration: flipDurationMs }}>
            <slot {item} />
        </div>
    {/each}
</section>

<SortableList bind:list={sensors}>
    <svelte:fragment let:item>
        <ListElement count={item.id} id={item.title} />
    </svelte:fragment>
</SortableList>

REPL
SortableList now only has to assume that the items have an id for keying.

Thank you very much for the prompt and thoughtful answer!

Making it generic would have been my next thought. Tank you very much for covering this right away as well.
I added you answer to my code and it works perfect.
VSCode complains that "Item" inside the fragment is of unknown type... Need to look into this another day.

@Georg: To handle the type errors you would probably need to introduce a generic type parameter and type the list property as something like T[]. Type parameters are now added as an attribute on the script, see this comment. If this sufficiently answered the question, you can accept it using the checkmark outline to the side.

perfect, I modified my ScrollableList.svelte:
by from 'export let list: any;' to 'export let list: any[];'. Now the errors disappeared.
Many thanks and greetings
Georg
